# Email Looping Issue with Exchange Server

Tags: email, exchange

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. So, feel free to let me know if we have a SE site specifically for Exchange.

In our exchange server, we have rules to send a  auto response for every incoming email. Now, the problem arises when the sender of the email has an out of office response set.

So, here is the scenario

1. Mark Williams sends an email to info@myorganization.com
2. My exchange server sends an automated response
3. Mark Williams Outlook sends me an Out of Office response
4. My exchange server treats that as a new incoming email and sends an automated response

Now, this goes on and on and in one instance, we ended up with 300,000 emails over a long weekend.

Is there a way that I can tell Exchange to send an automated response only once per day for an incoming email address?

We use Exchange 2003 and an upgrade to Exchange 2010 is planned for later this year.

Surely, we cannot be the only people to have this issue?

Comment: The problem is Mark Williams does not know how to use Out of Office response, and instead did an auto reply. My suggestion is to change reply to address (SMTP address) to something that doesn't exist or doesn't auto reply?

Comment: @shinjijai Well, I won't be able to ask Mark Williams to change his way of working. Second, no I am pretty sure that it is an Out of Office and not auto reply. I have tested it by setting my Out of Office on my outlook and the issue still happens. Unfortunately, the reply to address cannot be changed as we want to use the same email address for normal communication as well.

Comment: Unless something is changed, an Out of Office only sends out one reply to user per Out of Office.